# How to review the outline of `.rmd` file in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, r-markdown, knitr

[image]

I know vs code has ability to review ouline of `markdown`.
As to Rmarkdown with knitr,*.rmd files,how to review outline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to do install any extensions you can just simply go to the status bar and click on `Plain Text` and select Markdown from the menu that pops up and that will generate the outline treating the file as a Markdown file.

[image: Language selection]

If you want to make this change permanent across you workspace, add this to your `settings.json`

```
{
    "files.associations": {
    "*.rmd": "markdown",
  }
}
```

This is to tell VSCode to read all `.rmd` files as Markdown files and then it will be able to generate the outline.

[image: Demo]

Or you Could just install one of the extensions like [R-Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mikhail-Arkhipov.r)

This will parse your rmd file and generate an outline.

Comment: `"*.rmd": "markdown",` cannot recognize `{r}` chunk.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? If you are using code chucks, install the R language extension and R-Tools one